# Passport middlwares permissions routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

im using first time Passport laravel, but i still didnt understand quite is the difference between midlewareare auth:api and client:credentials (CheckClientCredentials ), doesnt these 2 types of middlware restrict routes? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

The auth:api middle-ware is used for authentication. Whenever user will call an api, the user has to provide the authentication token with it. It depends on you which api you are restricting. From that token we can recognize the user or get the user object from request. Following is the way to get the user from token.

```
  $user = $request->user();
```

for more information you can read the passport documentation at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport)

**Client Credentials Grant Tokens**

The client credentials grant is suitable for machine-to-machine authentication. For example, you might use this grant in a scheduled job which is performing maintenance tasks over an API.You can go through the doc at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens)

Comment: I see, but for example in my case, i have a mobile app that uses the API, to login or register a user and than manage his information, exactlly what your saying regarding the auth:api middle-ware, my question is that how can i protect the login or register from the public? Since is something that must be only by the mobile app? How can i handle this situation? Do i need to combine this 2 situations that you referenced above?

Comment: Well you can protect the route as follow.
Route::group(['prefix' => '/project', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
        Route::post('/save','Namespace/Controllername@actionname');
});

Comment: But wouldn the login or register routes would be avilable to the public?

Comment: you don't need to add this middle-ware to login and register. The routes should be public. you can restrict route as follow. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#via-middleware